# Contracts in substrate 3.0

Tags: ink, smart-contract

A customer has a substrate blockchain based on Tag 3.0.0
It uses pallet-contracts = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git",  tag = "v3.0.0"  }

The problem is that when I compile a smart contract with cargo contract and try to upload it (it uses the old-ui, see image below), it complains that the ABI is invalid.

'''Invalid ABI file — Error: Invalid JSON ABI structure supplied, expected a recent metadata version'''

It works Ok with the last version of substrate from the repo.

So my questions are:
.- Is it possible for cargo contract build contracts compatible with 3.0.0?
.- Is it possible to upgrade just the contract pallet on a substrate based on 3.0.0?

Thanks very much.
Regads;
Fernando

[image: Code Upload Functionality]

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to upgrade just the contract pallet on a substrate based on 3.0.0?

Yes, this is definitely possible! Substrate enables forkless runtime upgrades. [This tutorial here](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/forkless-upgrade/) walks through the steps of upgrading Substrate. Just be cautious when doing this and ensure the `pallet_contracts` is configured correctly for the new version. I recommend comparing the current [substrate-contracts-node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node) with your Substrate node and adding any differences relating to `pallet_contracts`. Note: The substrate-contracts-node uses instant block sealing, so make sure not to edit your node's consensus when comparing.

> Is it possible for cargo contract build contracts compatible with 3.0.0?

Yes, it is also possible to use a `cargo-contract` version that is compatible with ink! `v3.0.0`. To do this, you will likely need to downgrade `cargo-contract`. However, it is recommended to use the newest release of ink! (upgrade `pallet_contracts`, see above).

See [here](https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/releases) for `cargo-contract` releases.

For example, to downgrade:

```
cargo install cargo-contract --version 1.4.0 --force
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciate it. Ill test both options.

Comment: I've been trying to compile this way, but I got the same error. Debugging the UI, it seems it check if the contract bundle has:
a metadataVestion string, which is missimg
a spec object at the root level, but the compiler generates a V3: { spec: ... }

Maybe for substrate v3 (i mean the V3.0.0 tag in the repo) there is another way of writing smart contracts?

Thanks very much

Comment: @FernandoRuscitti If you are still having issues with this, upgrading from v3.0.0 and start following Polkadot releases should work. Currently this is `polkadot-v0.9.29`. The polkadot releases are the most up-to-date. Simply update all of the dependencies to follow that branch. Any changes to the client will require using a new binary for the nodes.